# How to open JP2 files just in browser?

Tags: google-chrome, firefox

When I click `JP2` files on this [page](http://sentinel-s2-l1c.s3-website.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/#tiles/10/S/DG/2015/12/7/0/), I get a file download dialog.

Is it possible to view these files just in the browser?

Comment: Under normal circumstances JP2 files are sent as an executable/binary file, hence the browser will see it as a normal file download. If amazon was to change the file MIME type to image/jp2, it should be possible to view the file directly via an extension JP2 viewer.

Comment: Only the server can change the MIME type.

Comment: Can't client igrone or substitute it?

Comment: No i don't think so or at least i've never seen that before.

Answer (score 0):

`JP2` stands for the [JPEG 2000](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JPEG_2000) format, which is not supported by any
major browser, since it is proprietary and covered by several patents.

For Chrome, I have found the add-on [TIF, TIFF Viewer with Drive](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/tif-tiff-viewer-with-driv/ejimgapgkloohjjiiamebgpcobfcaffl)
that claims support for JP2, but I have no experience with it and do not know
how well it works.

Answer (score 0):

[WebKit](https://webkit.org/) includes support for JPEG2000. Thus Safari and other WebKit-based browsers should be able to display these files.

Answer (score -2):

You cannot open your JP2 file because you have to right-click or long press the file. Then click "Open with" and choose an application.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).